# nginx cannot hide port from docker with reverse_proxy

Tags: location, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass, nginx-upstreams

In my nginx.conf using proxy_pass and upstream I still can't hide the port when redirecting.

I have two docker containers one with nginx, second with service I need to connect, but when I use `127.0.0.1/service` or `127.0.0.1/service/` I still move to the service window with port: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/login?next=%2Flab%3F`

But when I tried `localhost/service` or `localhost/service/` I get 404 error, but URL looks like the one I'm looking for: `http://localhost/login?next=%2Flab%2F%2F` but only with 404 error.

Nginx.conf:

```
upstream jupyter {
        server jupyterlab:8888;
}

server {
        listen nginx:80;

        server_name 127.0.0.1 www.127.0.0.1 ;


        location /jupyter {
                proxy_pass http://jupyter/lab/;
        }
}
```

p.s. I added / to `location /jupyter/` but it didn't change anything